# Moving macOS Mail App Icon From Dock to the Menu Bar

Tags: mail.app, dock, menu-bar

The Mail app built into macOS isn't the nicest thing in the world, the UI looks dated and Outlook is a much better alternative (for me at least).

The problem that I am facing is that I need the macOS Mail app to start at login and be running in the background due to the way [AltStore](https://altstore.io/) works. With Outlook also open, I have two Mail apps open, thus crowding my dock.

Is there a way to move the macOS Mail app away from the dock to the menu bar? Or in general, is there a way to move any app from the dock to the menu bar?

I use an app called [Hidden Bar](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/hidden-bar/id1452453066?mt=12) to collapse and hide some of the menu bar icons, with that, I will be able to completely remove the macOS mail app from my sights, even though it's still running in the background.

Comment: How many apps in your Dock do you _never_ use, or use infrequently? By default, macOS puts a slew of apps in the Dock, and they don't have to stay there if you don't want them.

Comment: I don't know of a way to generically move apps to the menu bar. I believe an app has to be specifically designed with menu bar support. There are ways, however, to remove icons of running apps from the Dock: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130390/hide-adium-or-any-other-apps-icon-in-the-dock

Comment: @jefe2000 I did take a look at that, unfortunately, the macOS mail app doesn't have an ```LSUIElement``` key in its ```info.plist``` file

Comment: @IconDaemon I am aware that I can remove apps that I don't need from the dock, and I don't have a lot of apps in the dock. It's just that I don't want two mail apps there when I'm only gonna use one of them.

Comment: I've learned about a couple options for customizing the macOS menu bar. One is called [SwiftBar](https://github.com/matryer/bitbar) and the other [BitBar](https://github.com/swiftbar/SwiftBar). They might have ways to display email info. Failing that, there may be a way to get a plugin or write a script to have them display email info.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I have found that [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar) can hide active applications.

Answer (score 0):

I know of one shareware applet called [MailBar](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/51517/mailbar) that does that (moving reading emails to the menu bar). It's fairly crude but it does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Don't know if it was true when you posted your answer, but MacUpdate now says that the app is no longer supported by the developer.