# "activate application" for Hidden Application

Tags: macos, applescript

How might I activate an application that is hidden from the OS X Dock?

The following only works for applications that are displayed in the Dock.

```
activate application "Firefox"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: Have you tested this with one of these techniques? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11592/hide-an-applications-dock-icon

Comment: +1, but you should improve your answer by adding 1) that it's an applescript 2) how to best implement it